# UIActivityViewControllers across iOS8/iOS9 iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

My app features a share button which uses activityViewController on iPhones (iOS8+) and iPads (iOS9+). As iPads only use UIPopoverController on iOS8 and activityViewController on iOS9, I've implemented some conditions which direct each device to the appropriate controller. The problem is, iTunes Connect has shown crashes on iPads using UIPopoverController:

-[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin]

Is the following code sound?

```
//if iOS9
if #available(iOS 9, *) {

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//if iOS8
else {
        
    //if iPad
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {

        let popoverCntlr = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityViewController)
            popoverCntlr.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)            
            
    }
    //if other
    else {
            
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash message ?

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: Run the app from Xcode and just see the console part of the Xcode when crash occurs. You will get a crash report.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the crash occurred on a users device, the program is on the app store. The device was and iPad Air 2 (9.2.1).

Comment: The only method will be to replicate the process that gave a crash by running the app from Xcode. I believe you do not have any SDK installed to report crashs. So it will be better to have some SDK's to report crashes. In the crash reports you will have detailed information about what caused the crash and other relevant data.